# CSS and HTML: Remove space between DIVs in given code

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div-message {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1020px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}

.msgbox {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', cursive;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2980B9;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    outline: 0;
}

/* tabs support */
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
     text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    border-bottom:0px;   
    width: 1020px;
}

ul.tab li {float: left;}

ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

ul.tab li a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

ul.tab li a:focus, .active {background-color: #ccc;}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 0px none #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    vertical-align: top;


}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
<ul class="tab">
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab1')">Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab2')">Options</a></li>
</ul> 
<div id="Tab1" class="tabcontent">
<div class='div-message'>
<textarea name='msgText' id='msgTextId' title='Messages' class='msgbox' readonly>Done!</textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is kind of tabbed panel with two tabs: MESSAGES and OPTIONS. When I click on MESSAGES a message box appears. Menu and message box should appear with grey background. It does appear. But how do I remove white space between menu and DIV, which contains message box?

Comment: Remove `padding` from `.tabcontent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `.tabcontent` has the following `padding` :

```
padding: 10px 10px;
```

Remove the top padding, or give it the same background color to get rid of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your `<div>` the following:

```
.div-message {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```